# How to make an Authorized HttpWebRequest to an ASP.NET MVC web app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, httpwebrequest, forms-authentication

I have an ASP.NET MVC web app that needs to allow a public API for downloading files.
Here is the action code:

```
public ActionResult DownloadFile(int id)
{
        var item = _context.GetRepositoryFileByID(id);
        if (item == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        var filePath = Path.Combine(AppConfig.FilesRepositoryStorageRoot, item.IntrenalFilePath);
        return File(filePath, "application/pdf");
}
```

this method is the a controller with an  `[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator,User")]` attribute set to it so only logged in users may access this action

now this action should allow users to make a request using the following code:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(fileDownloadUrl));
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

the thing that I am missing here is how do I pass an authorized `HttpWebRequest` to the `DownloadFile` action.

every thing I have tried will return the login page because the application cannot authorize the user and allow him to access the `DownloadFile` action.

I have tried to pass this Cookie value to the website that request the file using the following code

```
var authCookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(User.Identity.Name, true);
var authCoockieValue = authCookie.Value;
```

Then the website have used this value like this:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(fileDownloadUrl));
request.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Bearer " + authorization;
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

but this did not work.. I have also tried to pass the header with "Basic" instead of "Bearer" tag but it field as well.

I cam to terms with that I do not really understand how does an ASP.NET MVC application uses the `[Authorize]` attribute with `FormsAuthentication` so I humbly ask for your help...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found the solution.
You need to add an Authentication Cookie to the `HttpWebRequest` like this:

```
Uri fileDownloadURI = new Uri(fileDownloadUrl);
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(fileDownloadURI);
request.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Bearer " + authorization;
var authCookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(User.Identity.Name, true);
Cookie requestAuthCoockie = new Cookie()
{
    Expires = authCookie.Expires,
    Name = authCookie.Name,
    Path = authCookie.Path,
    Secure = authCookie.Secure,
    Value = authCookie.Value,
    Domain = fileDownloadURI.Host,
    HttpOnly = authCookie.HttpOnly,
};
request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
request.CookieContainer.Add(requestAuthCoockie);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Comment: What does the authorization variable contain?

Comment: If i want to call controller from some other application passing credentials, is it possible to access controller having authorize tag ?

Comment: If you have the authorization tag just add the cookie like the code displays

Comment: But what if i dont have authorization token ?

Comment: You'll have to provide some web service for authentication that will receive an input for login and password and return a token

Comment: In my lightswitch application user is already logged in and i have created one MVC controller which is having an action which returns file, but i want to check if this user is authenticated or not. when request is made at that point it shows that user is not authenticated for User.Identity.IsAuthenticated. how to authenticate it if request is created from lightswitch application ? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry mate .. I dono anything abut lightswitch .. Suggest you ask a new question ..

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what kind of authentication you are using. Generally, just simulate whatever the browser is doing when a user is logging in (you should know based on your code+web.config, or you can use a web debugging tool to capture the web requests). In case of a login form and cookies, just call the login action from your HttpWebRequest, and use a CookieContainer so that the resulting cookie is persisted to the next request. Or you could create a new authentication API, or even a whole new web application with different authentication.